# Azure web app (linux) connected SQL through hybrid connection fails over and over in timeout

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, azure-hybrid-connections

I have this problem i can't figure out.
I'm working on a dotnet core app through Azure web app on a linux server.
This app uses an Hybrid connection to connect the Azure app to a on premise SQL Db.

With the 2.0 net framework everything worked fine. But now i have to update the framework because 2.0 is no longer supported. So i decided to update the framework from .net 2.0 to .net 6.0.For making that work i needed to change some routing but i also needed to add a nuget `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package because `System.Data.SqlClient` didn't work anymore.

So far so good, i made the adjustments and when i test it locally everything works fine.

But when i want to test it on the Azure Web environment it doesn't work anymore and i get this strange error i can't resolve. The strange thing is that i didn't change the Hybrid Connection which worked with .net 2.0, the only thing i changed whas the nuget package...

What's also strange is that the Hybrid Connection Manager says it's connected, there is no firewall, i added TrustServerCertificate=true at the connection string, i increased the timeout on the SQL database, the TCP/IP is enabled on SQL Services, the ports and name are correct, i close all my sqlconnections in dotnet... But still somehow the connection through the hybrid connection takes to long and results in a timeout error..

> 2022-09-23T10:56:56.644776242Z Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.   The timeout period elapsed
> while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.
> This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
> unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
> to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=691;
> handshake=61012;

I tried everything... Does anyone know what i can try to resolve this issue?

Comment: I would start by trying to ping server IP and see if there is a route to the server.  This webpage give additional debug methods : https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/check-sql-server-instance-connectivity/